# Directory Path Issue with /pers

Tags: c#

In trying to create a button for a UI to launch a program, I came across an error with the following:

```
Process.Start("STK", 
      @"C:\Program Files (x86)\AGI\STK 11\bin\AgUiApplication.exe" /pers "STK");
```

The error I receive is that /pers does not exist in the current context.

I copied the file address exactly.

When selecting the .exe from my folder a separate box asks for which application, of which STK is the application I intend to run.

Any hints?

Comment: What exactly the "/pers" is ? Why do you need it?

Comment: I am not sure. It is in the target address that I copied from the properties of the application. The executable has three different options for different applications of the same company.

Comment: You may want to read something about string constants in C# (or any C-like language including JavaScript). If you can't and this is emergency - simply escape quotes.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you would run this program from the command line? This will help in identifying the correct way to execute from within C#.

Comment: Is AgUiApplication.exe the program you're trying to actually run?

Comment: The application is called STK11. The shortcut for STK11 is from this executable in its home folder.

Comment: Can you please give an example of how you would run it from the command line (with full paths) and arguments? It will clear up any ambiguity.

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\AGI\STK 11\bin\AgUiApplication.exe. From my understanding this should work?

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer then.

Comment: Adrian thank you very much that worked :) Sorry for the confusion I am still learning!!

Comment: No need to thank me. Correct action is to accept my answer as the correct one.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code:

```
Process.Start("STK", @"C:\Program Files (x86)\AGI\STK 11\bin\AgUiApplication.exe" /pers "STK");
```

Is not syntactically valid C# code. The quotes characters need to be escaped. Since you are using the verbatim notation (`@` on your string), the escaped version of the quote `"` character is `""`.

It also looks like you're possibly passing in application you want to run as part of the application's arguments instead of the filename argument. [The first](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5(v=vs.110).aspx) argument of `Process.Start` is

> The name of an application file to run in the process.

Therefore I believe the correct code to run this program should be:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\AGI\STK 11\bin\AgUiApplication.exe", @"/pers ""STK""");
```

Comment: Ah true yes this compiles now but it still won't run!

Comment: Yeah I didn't look beyond the syntax issue, but your parameters to `Process.Start` is also completely incorrect. If I get some time I'll update the answer with more info, but in the mean time, read the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

"/pers" and "STK" look like arguments being passed to the exe. If that's the case then they should be included inside the double quotes as following.

```
Process.Start("STK",  @"C:\Program Files (x86)\AGI\STK 11\bin\AgUiApplication.exe /pers ""STK""");
```

Comment: I tried it this way earlier, It still can't find the specified file.

Comment: The exe file exist at the location "C:\Program Files (x86)\AGI\STK 11\bin" ? can you check manually by navigating to that path in windows explorer?